# Migrate the Maven repository to another machine

Tags: maven, maven-3

Is it possible to migrate the Maven repository to another machine without having to reconfigure each item added to it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought I had already marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just copy the .m2/repository folder to another machine.
FYI, you can execute mvn install and it will download all dependencies once again, but it will take  while.