# Copy Maven repository to another computer

Tags: java, maven

Is there some index or cache that needs to be refreshed or deleted when I copy over the Maven repository from another computer?

I would like to copy the local Maven repository from my laptop for use on another computer that is effectively offline.  After copying the files from [~/.m2/repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15720575/935154) it does not work as expected.  When I execute `mvn package -o` I get an error that it cannot find one of the artifacts from the new repository:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project [...]: Could not resolve dependencies for project [...]: 
Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3.0 has not been downloaded from it before.
```

But I do have the artifact in the folder at `~/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.3.0` that was copied in from the other computer. (This particular one is not public; it is stored on our company Nexus server which cannot be reached from the target system.)

Comment: could you make sure it is referring to the same place where you copied artifacts by supplying `-X` and watching logs

Comment: I am getting same issue. Please share your solution that was worked in your case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maven uses the "update policy" in the [settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) file to decide whether to download the artifact or to use the one in the local repository if available.

If you don't want Maven to update your dependencies, you should configure `<updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>`. You also need to use the same repository `<id>`s in both locations.

So if you are only using Maven's Central Repository, your `repository` configuration would look something like this:

```
<repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>Maven Central</name>
  <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your comment about needing the same ID's did it.   I didn't think the repository name would matter since the Jars were there and it was in offline mode.  For others reading this, note the remote repository name is in the _remote.repositories file within the local repository folder for the artifact.  This apparently needs to match a repository in settings.xml.

Comment: @jcadcell thanks a lot! Your comment is very usefull for me!